# typedef structures pointer issue

Tags: c, typedef

**SOLUTION: THE TIMEOUT ISNT GIVING ALL ARGUMENTS THE CALLBACK FUNCTION NEEDS. THE PRINT_OUT CODE WORKS ON OTHER PLACES. IT WAS AN INTERNAL MISTAKE BY ME !!!**

I have declared following types/structures:

```
// -> month marked days storage structures

typedef gint _month[31];

typedef struct month_all {
  _month jan;
  _month feb;
  _month mar;
  _month apr;
  _month may;
  _month jun;
  _month jul;
  _month aug;
  _month sep;
  _month oct;
  _month nov;
  _month dec;
} months;

// -> general structure

typedef struct signal_map {
  widgets widg;
  months mnt;
} signal_map_data;
```

And my (**updated**) code:

```
void load_marked_days (gint month, signal_map_data *smd){
  #ifdef debug
    g_print ("-> load_marked_days\n");
  #endif
  char buf[100];
  sprintf (buf, "%d", smd->mnt.jan[0]);
  g_print (buf);
}

// ----------------- main ----------------- /

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder;
  signal_map_data smd;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new ();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (gtkBuilder, "gui.glade", NULL);

  smd.widg.wmw.wnd = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "wnd") );
  smd.widg.wmw.btn_new = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_new") );
  smd.widg.wmw.btn_open = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_open") );
  smd.widg.wmw.btn_save = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_save") );
  smd.widg.wmw.btn_add = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_add") );
  smd.widg.wmw.btn_delete = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_delete") );
  smd.widg.wmw.tb_imgpath = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "tb_imgpath") );
  smd.widg.wmw.btn_path = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_path") );
  smd.widg.wmw.btn_make = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_make") );
  smd.widg.wmw.calendar = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "calendar") );
  smd.widg.wmw.img_month = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "img_month") );
  smd.widg.wmw.combobox1 = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "combobox1") );
  smd.widg.wmw.treeview = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "treeview") );

  smd.widg.wdaw.dlg_add = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "dlg_add") );
  smd.widg.wdaw.lb_q = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "lb_q") );
  smd.widg.wdaw.tb_text = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "tb_text") );
  smd.widg.wdaw.combobox2 = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "combobox2") );
  smd.widg.wdaw.btn_select_add = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_select_add") );
  smd.widg.wdaw.btn_cancel_add = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_cancel_add") );

  smd.widg.wdbw.dlg_browse = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "dlg_browse") );
  smd.widg.wdbw.btn_open_folder = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_open_folder") );
  smd.widg.wdbw.btn_cancel_browse = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_cancel_browse") );

  smd.widg.wdow.dlg_open = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "dlg_open") );
  smd.widg.wdow.btn_open_file = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_open_file") );
  smd.widg.wdow.btn_cancel_open = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_cancel_open") );

  smd.widg.wdsw.dlg_save = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "dlg_save") );
  smd.widg.wdsw.btn_save_file = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_save_file") );
  smd.widg.wdsw.btn_cancel_save = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "btn_cancel_save") );

  smd.widg.lst.lst1 = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "liststore1") );
  smd.widg.lst.lst2 = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "liststore2") );
  smd.widg.lst.lst3 = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (gtkBuilder, "liststore3") );

  memset (smd.mnt.jan, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.jan);
  memset (smd.mnt.feb, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.feb);
  memset (smd.mnt.mar, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.mar);
  memset (smd.mnt.apr, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.apr);
  memset (smd.mnt.may, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.may);
  memset (smd.mnt.jun, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.jun);
  memset (smd.mnt.jul, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.jul);
  memset (smd.mnt.aug, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.aug);
  memset (smd.mnt.sep, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.sep);
  memset (smd.mnt.oct, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.oct);
  memset (smd.mnt.nov, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.nov);
  memset (smd.mnt.dec, 0, sizeof smd.mnt.dec);

  char buf[100];
  sprintf (buf, "%d", smd.mnt.jan[0]);
  g_print (buf);

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (gtkBuilder, &smd);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (gtkBuilder) );

  g_timeout_add (1000, (GSourceFunc) load_marked_days, &smd);
```

But How can I access the single day (like `_month[0]` for the 1st of a month) to get it's value?

This, from inside of `load_marked_days` is wrong:

```
char buf[100];
sprintf (buf, "%d", smd->mnt.jan[0]);
g_print (buf);
```

> -163321601

```
char buf[100];
sprintf (buf, "%d", &smd->mnt.jan[0]);
g_print (buf);
```

> 4201655

How to get my value??? Both doesn't return `0` ...
But in my main function the print of this "day" works and print `0` ..?
Whats wrong with my pointer?

Comment: At the moment, your question is possibly not answerable with the details provided. I think the behavior of `load_marked_days` would be useful. Otherwise, "How can I access a single day" is pretty straightforward and you appear to be doing it like anybody else would.

Comment: `smd->mnt->jan[0]` is correct. The most likely problem is the lifetime of your variables. If any of them is declared within the scope of a function (hence on the stack), but are "used" outside the scope of that function, you'll get a segfault. To know for sure, add your complete code (or more precisely, a minimal yet complete version of your code that has the same problem)

Comment: The symptoms you describe appear to match those when the wrong type of data is provided to `printf`. For example, `%d` tells `printf` to expect an `int` argument, however the type you've given is `gint`. According to [the manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html#gint), this should be compatible, however to be safe you might want to verify that by diving into your preprocessed source code.

Comment: I've added more detailed code. Have a look again pls.

Comment: Try Amits suggestion, i.e. declare the smd variables as globals and try again. At a glance everything looks OK apart from the variable storage is on the stack.

Comment: @MartinFischer: `sizeof mnt.jan / sizeof mnt.jan[0]` gives you the number of elements in the array. You need to know the number of *bytes* to set to zero. So `sizeof(mnt.jan)` should be adequate.

Comment: @AndyG updated again. Have a look pls!

Comment: @MartinFischer: I think I have to agree with Amit that this has to do with the lifetime of your variables at this point. What is the expected memory management behavior to data passed to `g_timeout_add`? If you allocated everything on the heap with `malloc` does the problem go away (albeit with a possible leak)?

Comment: @AndyG it works with every other function but not with a timeout call ... why not?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION: THE TIMEOUT ISNT GIVING ALL ARGUMENTS THE CALLBACK FUNCTION NEEDS. THE PRINT_OUT CODE WORKS ON OTHER PLACES. IT WAS AN INTERNAL MISTAKE BY ME !!!** – Martin Fischer